# class issue in C++

Tags: c++, oop, class, methods

I have this in furniture.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Furniture {
public:
    Furniture();
    virtual ~Furniture();
    void setname(string name);
    void setprice(double price);
    int getprice();
    string getname();
private:
    string name;
    int price;
protected:
    static int NumberOfItems;
    int Id;

}
```

and this in furniture.cpp

```
#include "furniture.h"

void Furniture::setname(string name) {
    this->name = name;
}
string Furniture::getname()
{
    return this->name;
}
void Furniture::setprice(double price) {
    this->price = price;
}
int Furniture::getprice() {
    return this->price;
}

int main() {
    Furniture *model = new Furniture();
    model->setname("FinalDestiny");
    model->setprice(149.99);
    cout<<"Model name: "<<model->getname()<<" - price = "<<model->getprice();
}
```

But I get some errors like:

Error   1   error C2628: 'Furniture' followed by 'void' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)  c:\final\facultate\poo\laborator 1\furniture.cpp    3   1   POO_lab

Error   2   error C2556: 'Furniture Furniture::setname(std::string)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'void Furniture::setname(std::string)'  c:\final\facultate\poo\laborator 1\furniture.cpp    3   1   POO_lab

Error   3   error C2371: 'Furniture::setname' : redefinition; different basic types c:\final\facultate\poo\laborator 1\furniture.cpp    3   1   POO_lab

Error   5   error C2264: 'Furniture::setname' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called    c:\final\facultate\poo\laborator 1\furniture.cpp    19  1   POO_lab

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Error 1 error C2628: 'Furniture' followed by 'void' is illegal **(did you forget a ';'?)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a `;` at the end of the class definition in your header file.

```
// ...snipped...

protected:
    static int NumberOfItems;
    int Id;

}; // <-- here
```

Answer (score 5):

You've forgotten a semicolon at the end of your class definition.

```
// ...
protected:
    static int NumberOfItems;
    int Id;
}; // <--
```

I hate that about C++ :)

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Thanks, fixed. Y'know, you can always just edit it in ;)

Answer (score 3):

Two things;

- You're not ending your class definition with a `;`, you need one at the end of furniture.h.
- You've declared that there's a constructor and destructor, but neither is implemented in your .cpp file.